Component doesn't re-render when updating state using useReducer in another component
I have three files store.js where I define my reducer and initial state. ComponentA.js where I dispatch changes to the state and ComponentB.js where I listen to state changes and render the state. But the ComponentB is not re-rendering when I dispatch from ComponentA, why?
// store.js

import { useReducer } from "react";

const initialState = {
  firstName: "",
  lastName: "",
};

function reducer(state, { fieldName, fieldValue }) {
  return {
    ...state,
    [fieldName]: fieldValue,
  };
}

export function useForm() {
  return useReducer(reducer, initialState);
}

// ComponentA.js

import { useForm } from "./store";

export function ComponentA() {
  const [{ firstName }, dispatch] = useForm();

  return (
    <input
      type="text"
      value={firstName}
      onChange={(e) => {
        dispatch({
          fieldName: "firstName",
          fieldValue: e.target.value,
        });
      }}
    />
  );
}

// ComponentB.js

import { useForm } from "./store";

export function ComponentB() {
  const [{ firstName }] = useForm();

  return <p>{firstName}</p>;
}

// App.js

import { ComponentA } from "./ComponentA";
import { ComponentB } from "./ComponentB";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
      <ComponentA />
      <ComponentB />
    </div>
  );
}

Code sandbox link https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/usereducer-rfhnvz
Is this behaviour expected?

Every time you call useForm you create a new reducer. If you want to share date between components use context

Your components are using different state. To share the state between different components without using context or external state libraries (like zustand), you can pass the state and the dispatch function as props to child components.
const [state, dispatch] = useForm();

return  <ComponentA state={state} dispatch={dispatch} />
      <ComponentB  state={state} dispatch={dispatch}/>

